# create href and add var and by java script

Tags: javascript, href

I struggle on this , its look very simple but I cant do it , I have javascript loop I want to print the information inside the table works fine for me , but I want the last cell of every row should be an href with adding id to it so href will be changed for last cell first row  would be edite next cell in the next row will be edit, those number created by the data come from data in the loop check the code, I tried with a single quote or double quote but it doesn't  work it treat the what inside href as a string, not function or something have to value

```js
var config = {
  apiKey: "my_secret_key",
  authDomain: "xyz.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xyz.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xyz",
  storageBucket: "xyz.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "0000000000000"

};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    var_data = doc.data().firt_name;
    var_last = doc.data().last_name;
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + doc.data().first_name + " </td>" +
      "<td>" + doc.data().last_name + "</td>" + "<td>" + doc.data().active +
      "<td>" + "<td><a href='x.php?id='doc.data().first_name >Edit</a></tr>";

  });

});
```

```html
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
           <table id="table" >
                <th>name</th>
                <th>last</th>
                <th>active</th>
                <th>id</th>
                <tr>
                    
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Youll probably have to do something like href='x.php?id=' + doc.data().firstname

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like this:

```js
var config = {
  apiKey: "my_secret_key",
  authDomain: "xyz.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xyz.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xyz",
  storageBucket: "xyz.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "0000000000000"

};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    var_data = doc.data().firt_name;
    var_last = doc.data().last_name;
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + doc.data().first_name + " </td>" +
      "<td>" + doc.data().last_name + "</td>" + "<td>" + doc.data().active +
      "<td>" + "<td><a href='x.php?id=" + doc.data().first_name + "'>Edit</a></tr>";

  });

});
```

```html
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
           <table id="table" >
                <th>name</th>
                <th>last</th>
                <th>active</th>
                <th>id</th>
                <tr>
                    
                </tr>
            </table>
```